High poly modelling problem
I'm having some trouble with my vintage calculator model. I started by modelling it in low poly and UV unwrapping, and then I moved on to high poly modelling. While doing high poly modelling, I noticed a line (which you can see in the photo), and I know that it's because of the multires modifier that I should add a loop cut, but I'm not sure where or which face to add it.




It's probably the triangle fans on the corners. Try adding another loop on the flat part and merge the corners of the triangles before they reach the outer corner of the flat part. That may help.

No way to answer this without the blend file. https://blend-exchange.com

FWIW this is essentially the exact opposite of the way you want to do HP>LP modeling. You almost always go Blockout > HP > LP > Unwrap/Bake. Specifically because you wind up having to adjust your LP to match the HP silhouette, fix random baking artefacts etc. You won't know where you mesh needs adjusting to fit the HP if you haven't even made the HP yet.

Well, recently I follow a course by Emiel Sleegers : https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/lqYj/hero-game-asset-creation-in-depth-tutorial-course
In that course the pathway of making a model was introduced as low poly->  UV unwrapping ->  high poly -> Baking
As you it's different, which one is okay?
